# Having trouble adding gaps in between li tags

Tags: css

```
  <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Brantford Grandview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brantford Vintage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kingston <br/>River Park</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
        </ul>
```

It's a pretty basically drop down menu Im building. Right now, I'm just adding a top border to every li giving it a grey line. However, what I want is a 1or 2px gap between the links so the user can see the bg behind. I tried add a div tab in between the li with a height of 1px, but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the CSS you've tried to get this too work. Adding a `padding` or `margin` property should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the CSS, but I would try fooling around with `margin-top` or something. It mainly depends on what element the background is being applied to, in your case you would need to apply it to the `<li>`. Let me know if I need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

A padding inside the li would work.

```
 li{
    padding-top:2px;
 }
```

would leave a 2px space inside the li and show the background.